# What are these very saturated-purple flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

I found these flowers in Saint-Petersburg, Russia in the end of July, growing near a house, apparently planted by someone along with lots of other flowers. These look *very* saturated purple: my phone failed to capture this purpleness, instead rendering them red regardless of white balance setting, and with a DSLR I was able to capture something closer to their real color, although still not ideally (see the photo below).

What is the name of these flowers?

[image: Photo taken with a DSLR]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [*lychnis coronaria*](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/10602/i-lychnis-coronaria-i/details), or the rose campion. There are other English names such as "dusty miller" from the grey leaves.

In the UK, if you grow it as a garden flower it will self-seed and spread everywhere. The only "cultivation" required is getting rid of it where you don't want it growing!